# Where to report Google Groups bugs?

Tags: google-groups

Where to send bug reports for Google Groups?

When I mark a post as spam in the Group I manage, I almost always get this error:

[image]

When I click [Google Support](http://support.google.com/groups/bin/request.py?contact_type=contact_policy) link, I get this very unhelpful page:
(it contains nothing clickable except "Report a legal issue")

[image]

The Group about Google Groups was [closed in 2010](http://groups.google.com/group/groupsknownissues/browse_thread/thread/beaa1543ecc87df3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Settings (the Gear icon), there should be a link that says "Send Feedback"

This tool will allow you to give a description and send a screenshot of the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was using the old Google Groups, so my Settings gear only contained "Settings" and "Help". Switching to the new Google Groups revealed this "Report an issue about Google Groups" item.