# Submitting bugs and enhancement requests to Google Documents webapp

Tags: google, google-docs, bug-trackers

## Question

Does Google provide a public bug tracking system, issue tracking
system, or enhancement tracking system (similar to, say,
[Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/)) into which their users could submit reports to actual
Google developers and not just other users (note: see below the
*Dead-End Reference Material* that specifically excludes Googles
support forums)?

## Dead-End Reference Material:

The following are links to my web sleuthing that turned out to not be answers to this question:

1. Note that I already know about the various Google-app-specific Google support forums (e.g. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/2583/14529), and that is not the answer I am looking for.
2. [Google search: how to submit bug requests to google documents](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20submit%20enhancement%20requests%20to%20google%20documents&hl=en&lr=lang_en#hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&sclient=psy-ab&q=how%20to%20submit%20bug%20requests%20to%20google%20documents&oq=how%20to%20submit%20bug%20requests%20to%20google%20documents&gs_l=serp.3...13765.13967.0.14813.3.3.0.0.0.2.161.334.1j2.3.0.les;..0.0...1c..4.psy-ab.GCgPjXo234M&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42768644,d.cGE&fp=f4bef204746361a4&biw=1918&bih=992)
3. [Is there any where to submit feature requests for Gmail (or other Google apps)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2580/is-there-any-where-to-submit-feature-requests-for-gmail-or-other-google-apps)
4. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35171/14529
5. [Report Gmail Bug](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/request.py?&contact_type=inproduct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no public bug tracking system for those Google products. Sometimes Google employees participate in discussions in forums, like here: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/2E9tLNWdhAw

Note that Google Employees have the small Google icon next to their name.

If you are a Google Apps for Business customer, you might be eligible for contacting Google support via phone or email: http://contact.googleapps.com/?&rd=1

Comment: Thanks. Marking as the answer as the answer is "no".